# How to create a string in PHP that is equivalent to yyyyMMddHHmmssffff

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to integrate with some VB code that generates a string using

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff")`

The closest I can get to this in PHP has been

`date('YmdHis')`

But this lacks the milliseconds,

I have tried playing with `microtime` e.g.

`date('YmdHis',time()).substr(str_replace(".","",microtime(true)),10,17)`

But sometimes this results in a shorter string

Comment: Milliseconds are shown using `v` as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). See the note just above the milliseconds entry though...use the proper DateTime object to get a better result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` function always returns zero for microseconds. Use [DateTime -> format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) and chop the last two digits off so that 4 fractional digits are left.

```php
substr((new DateTime()) -> format('YmdHisu'), 0, 18);
```